# get uploading status for Youtube API with PHP

Tags: php, api, youtube

i`m using **php**, i upload video on my chanel. how i can get load percentage my video?

i use **curl** for upload file, on kohana framework.

please help me, i need for example **"45%"**

```
Curl::post(Yt::$url_GetUploadToken, $data, $aHeader, 0, $aOpt );
```

how i can get percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do won't work.

PHP is a server-side language. When you tell it to do something (for example upload a file) it will continue to work on that until it is done. You want the script to both upload and during the uploading report how many percent of the file is uploaded.

This is one of the main reasons why people use Flash to upload files. Flash can upload a file, and at the same time gather information and display it to the user during the operation.

The only way this possible could work it submitting the form using Ajax and use Ajax to check the status of the upload at intervals. I am not sure if this would work either, as it require PHP to somehow save the current progression, and I have no idea how you do that when the entire upload is done via cURL.